# Objective-C 2.0 ABI specification

Tags: objective-c, abi, language-specifications

Does documentation for the Objective-C 2.0 ABI exist somewhere on the Internet? The [release notes](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-493.9/ReleaseNotes.rtf) for [`objc4-493.9`](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-493.9/) say:

> Forthcoming documentation will describe the ABI for the use of compilers and developer tools only.

Has it since been released? The closest such reference is Apple's [Objective-C runtime reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html), but this only describes the public-facing API rather than the implementation details. In fact, it even mentions the ABI in passing:

> In addition, the new Objective-C ABI (not described here) [...]

Unfortunately the new ABI is not hyperlinked in the aforementioned text. :-) Is my only option to grok the source code for the `objc4` runtime and Clang's `CGObjCNonFragileABIMac` code-generation projects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. Analysis of the clang and runtime source are your only options, aside from perhaps emailing the clang and Apple obj-c lists and seeing if anyone wants to respond. I know several of the people responsible for the GNU runtime subscribe to the clang list, so that may be a start.

Comment: That's a bummer. That's a good tip w.r.t. the mailing lists, I might just do that.